# Среды разработки

Tags: android, c++

Можно ли писать android-приложения на C++ и если да, то хотелось бы узнать, в каких средах разработки это можно осуществить.

Answer (score 2):

Да, это возможно, для этого потребуется Android NDK(Native Development Kit). В качестве среды разработки можно использовать Android Studio или Eclipse.
http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/ndk/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Да, большую часть логики можно реализовать в виде NDK-библиотеки. Из неё вы сможете даже взаимодействовать с системными JAVA-библиотеками и сервисами, посредством JNI. Однако, это далеко не так то просто и прозрачно, как хотелось бы. И да, вам всё-равно потребуется написать хотя бы минимальную прослойку на Java.

Если вам необходимо быстро разрабатывать приложения с богатым разнообразием элементов пользовательского интерфейса, то лучше посмотреть в сторону [QT](http://www.qt.io/) - разработку интерфейса вы будете вести в [Qt Creator](http://www.qt.io/ide/), писать же код можете либо тоже в Qt Creator, либо просто в любой удобной вам IDE для C++. JAVA-прослойку для андройд при этом будет формировать сам QT в процессе компиляции.

Если же вы хотите писать игры, то рекомендую взглянуть на [Marmalade](http://docs.madewithmarmalade.com/display/MD/Marmalade+CPP).